# Why goes git revert result in conflicts?

Tags: git

Lets day I have the following commits in git log:

```
previous commits --> bug fix --> pep8 the whole file (head)

-----------------------------------------------------
commit abcdefg2
pep8 the whole file

commit abcdefg1
bug fix
```

Now that I want to revert the pep8 changes by running:

```
git revert abcdefg1
```

Then I get a lot of conflicts... I wonder what I have done? I am not sure which commit to use in the revert, abcdefg1 or abcdefg2?

Comment: Revert a commit it's the same that create a NEW commit rolling back the changes, that's why you're getting conflits

Comment: I don't think you should be getting conflicts based on your new, substantially different, question.  Also, if you haven't yet pushed this branch you could either nuke the `pep3` commit or simply amend it later on.

Comment: I tried on a simplied version of my project, and I should have reverted `abcdefg2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a diagram showing the state of your branch after applying the revert commit:

```
branch: ... I -- A -- B -- C
```

Here commit `A` is `pep8 the whole file`, `B` is the bug fix, and `C` is the revert of commit `A`.  However, functionally speaking, reverting commit `A` leaves your branch in the same state as the following:

```
branch: ... I -- B
```

In other words, after applying the revert commit it is as if you had just laid down the bug fix on top of some earlier commit.  Most likely, this resulted in some conflicts which must be resolved.  You could test this theory yourself, or just accept that it is perfectly normal for a conflict to happen when doing a revert.

Comment: hi @tim-biegeleisen, I think you misunderstood the order of commits in my question(I now updated it to make it more clear) can you please update your answer?

Comment: I didn't misunderstand anything, you provided incorrect information in your question.

Comment: Actually in this case the order of the commits doesn't matter now, I was confused with the <commit> param with reset command. git revert <commit> actually cheery picks the commit to revert. Your answer does help understanding what I did wrong. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

`git revert` and `git cherry-pick` are merge operations.

For cherry-pick, the cherry-picked commit's parent is the base, the cherry-picked commit is the "their" tip, your checkout is the "our" tip.

```
...B---C     git cherry-pick C

...H         with H the HEAD
```

is a merge with `B` as the base, it merges the changes from B to C with the changes from B to H.  This might take some quiet time to appreciate, it's worth spending it.

Revert is simply the reverse:

```
...T---R    git revert R

...H        with H the HEAD
```

merges the changes from R to T with the changes from R to H.